# Pandas melt to copy values and insert new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have two dataframes like as shown below

```
test_id,status,revenue,cnt_days,age     
1,passed,234.54,3,21          
2,passed,543.21,5,29
11,failed,21.3,4,35
15,failed,2098.21,6,57             
51,passed,232,21,80     
75,failed,123.87,32,43

df1 = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')


test_id,var_name,score,sign
1,revenue,10,pos
1,cnt_days,5,neg
1,age,15,pos
2,revenue,11,pos
2,cnt_days,3,neg
2,age,25,pos

df2 = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
```

I would like to do the below

a) Bring the value of variables `revenue`, `cnt_days`, `age` from df1 and store it in df2 under a new column `var_value`. We copy only these 3 variables because they are present under `df2[var_name]`

For ex: We have df1 column names stored as values in df2 under `var_name`.

Now, I would like to bring their values and store it under `var_value` for each matching `test_id` and corresponding `column name`.

I was trying something like below

```
out_df = df1.merge(df2,on='test_ids').melt(var_name='var_name')
out_df.drop_duplicates()
```

But this results in incorrect output.

I expect my output to be like as below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in ouput is not column `status` fors rmove it by `drop`, then use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and add to `df2` by left join in [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
out_df = df2.merge(df1.drop('status',1)
                      .melt('test_id', var_name='var_name', value_name='var_value'),
                   how='left')
print (out_df)
   test_id  var_name  score sign  var_value
0        1   revenue     10  pos     234.54
1        1  cnt_days      5  neg       3.00
2        1       age     15  pos      21.00
3        2   revenue     11  pos     543.21
4        2  cnt_days      3  neg       5.00
5        2       age     25  pos      29.00
```

If order of columns is important:

```
out_df.insert(2, 'var_value', out_df.pop('var_value'))
print (out_df)
   test_id  var_name  var_value  score sign
0        1   revenue     234.54     10  pos
1        1  cnt_days       3.00      5  neg
2        1       age      21.00     15  pos
3        2   revenue     543.21     11  pos
4        2  cnt_days       5.00      3  neg
5        2       age      29.00     25  pos
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and a left [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df2.merge(df1.melt(id_vars=['test_id', 'status'],
                   var_name='var_name', value_name='var_value'),
          on=['test_id', 'var_name'], how='left'
         )
```

output:

```
   test_id  var_name  score sign  status  var_value
0        1   revenue     10  pos  passed     234.54
1        1  cnt_days      5  neg  passed       3.00
2        1       age     15  pos  passed      21.00
3        2   revenue     11  pos  passed     543.21
4        2  cnt_days      3  neg  passed       5.00
5        2       age     25  pos  passed      29.00
```